# Install wireless drivers on a Dell e1505 manually

Tags: 12.10, wireless, drivers, broadcom

So I'm trying to install the Broadcom BCM4311 driver on 12.10 but the thing is that I don't have any way to use Ethernet to actually download it. Luckily I'm dual booting it with windows so I can download whatever I need from there and put it on my flash drive, so can anyone point me to the download page on where I can get the required packages? I need some instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When  I have been stuck away from home without internet trying to install the Broadcom WIFI packages I did find a very useful way was to use the installation source (for me it was a USB pen drive - which I had usually as I had just done a reinstall as I had broken my netbook!)

I found from experience that I could not always rely on getting to an ethernet connection so used the following method which draws from resources on the installation USB.

It meant that I could get up and running on my own (not having windows meant I had to be able to do this)
This guide is from one of the Community Help Wiki and gives an excellent guide to all things Broadcom but this link is specifically about trying it offline.

[Install Broadcom with no internet access - Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#STA_-_No_Internet_access)

In reality installs the bcmwl-kernel-source package from the restricted folder under ../pool/restricted/b/bcmwl on the Ubuntu install media/USB/CD

Have a go and let us know how you get on.